# Palindrome and Reverse a String Problems (JavaScript, Python)

Tags: python, javascript, beginner, algorithm, strings

#### Problem 1

Given a string, the task is to reverse the string and return a reversed string.

#### Problem 2

Given a string, return true if the string is a palindrome or false if it is not.

### Code

Just for practicing, I've implemented reverse string and palindrome problems using JavaScript and Python. If you'd like to review the codes and provide any change/improvement recommendations, please do so and I appreciate that.

#### JavaScript

```js
// Problem 1
// Given a string, return true if the string is a palindrome
// or false if it is not.  Palindromes are strings that
// form the same word if it is reversed. *Do* include spaces
// and punctuation in determining if the string is a palindrome.
// --- Examples:
//   abba => true
//   abc => false

// Problem 2
// Given a string, return a new string with the reversed
// order of characters
// --- Examples
//   apple => leppa
//   hello => olleh
//   Greetings! => !sgniteerG



// This method tests if the string is a palindrome using four reverse string functions
function check_palindrome(original_string) {
    original_string = original_string.toLowerCase();
    let reversed_string_1 = reverse_string_built_in(original_string);
    let reversed_string_2 = reverse_string_reduce(original_string);
    let reversed_string_3 = reverse_string_for_of_loop(original_string);
    let reversed_string_4 = reverse_string_negative_for_loop(original_string);

    // If the original string is a palindrome
    if (reversed_string_1 === original_string && reversed_string_2 === original_string && reversed_string_3 === original_string && reversed_string_4 === original_string) {
        return true;
        // If the original string is not a palindrome
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// This method is an slightly optimized version of checking for palindrome
function check_palindrome_optimized(original_string) {
    original_string = original_string.toLowerCase();
    count = 0;
    return original_string.split('').every((char, i) => {
        count++;
        if (count > Math.floor(original_string.length / 2)) {
            return true
        }
        return char === original_string[original_string.length - i - 1];
    });
}

// This method uses reverse() built in function
function reverse_string_built_in(original_string) {
    return original_string.split('').reverse().join('');
}

// This method uses for of loop
function reverse_string_for_of_loop(original_string) {
    let reversed_string = '';

    for (let char of original_string) {
        reversed_string = char + reversed_string;
    }

    return reversed_string;
}

// Using negative for loop and contact
function reverse_string_negative_for_loop(original_string) {
    let reversed_string = '';

    for (var i = original_string.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed_string = reversed_string.concat(original_string[i]);
    }
    return reversed_string;
}


//Using reduce() method
function reverse_string_reduce(original_string) {
    return original_string.split('').reduce((reversed_string, char) => char + reversed_string, '');
}


// Here, we are testing our palindrome words
words_array = ['apple', 'kayak', 'abc1221cba', 'reviver', 'redivider', '1736', 'deified', 'Anna', 'Able was I ere I saw Elba', "Madam, I'm Adam", 'civic', 'RaDar', 'Never odd or even', 'LeVeL', 'kayak', 'racecar', 'Doc, note: I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod', 'redder', 'madam', '1991', 'refer'];

for (let word of words_array) {
    if (check_palindrome_optimized(word) === true && check_palindrome(word) === true) {
        console.log(' "'.concat(word, '" is a palindrome!'));
    } else {
        console.log(' "'.concat(word, '" is not a palindrome!'));
    }
}
```

#### Python

```
def reverse_string(original_string):
    '''
    Returns a reversed string give a string
    '''
    reversed_string = ''
    for char in original_string:
        reversed_string = char + reversed_string

    return reversed_string


def reverse_string_slice(original_string):
    '''Returns a reversed string give a string'''
    return original_string[::-1]


def check_palindrome(original_string):
    '''Returns true if an input string is a palindrome'''
    original_string = original_string.lower()
    if reverse_string_slice(original_string) == original_string and reverse_string(original_string) == original_string:
        return True
    return False


# Here, we are testing our palindrome words
words_array = ['apple', 'kayak', 'abc1221cba', 'reviver', 'redivider', '1736', 'deified', 'Anna', 'Able was I ere I saw Elba', "Madam, I'm Adam", 'civic', 'RaDar',
               'Never odd or even', 'LeVeL', 'kayak', 'racecar', 'Doc, note: I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod', 'redder', 'madam', '1991', 'refer']


delimiter = '-'*50

for word in words_array:
    print(delimiter)
    print(f'The reverse of "{word}" is "{reverse_string(word)}"')
    if check_palindrome(word) == True:
        print(f' "{word}" is a palindrome!')
    else:
        print(f' "{word}" is not a palindrome!')
```

#### Output

```
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "apple" is "elppa"
 "apple" is not a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "kayak" is "kayak"
 "kayak" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "abc1221cba" is "abc1221cba"
 "abc1221cba" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "reviver" is "reviver"
 "reviver" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "redivider" is "redivider"
 "redivider" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "1736" is "6371"
 "1736" is not a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "deified" is "deified"
 "deified" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "Anna" is "annA"
 "Anna" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "Able was I ere I saw Elba" is "ablE was I ere I saw elbA"
 "Able was I ere I saw Elba" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "Madam, I'm Adam" is "madA m'I ,madaM"
 "Madam, I'm Adam" is not a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "civic" is "civic"
 "civic" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "RaDar" is "raDaR"
 "RaDar" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "Never odd or even" is "neve ro ddo reveN"
 "Never odd or even" is not a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "LeVeL" is "LeVeL"
 "LeVeL" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "kayak" is "kayak"
 "kayak" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "racecar" is "racecar"
 "racecar" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "Doc, note: I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod" is "doc no teid I .ssentaf a stneverp reven tsaf A .tnessid I :eton ,coD"
 "Doc, note: I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod" is not a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "redder" is "redder"
 "redder" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "madam" is "madam"
 "madam" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "1991" is "1991"
 "1991" is a palindrome!
--------------------------------------------------
The reverse of "refer" is "refer"
 "refer" is a palindrome!
```

Comment: I presume, by "string" you mean "a sequence of Latin letters"? Otherwise, your problems would be much harder to solve. See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776621/989121

Comment: Typically, punctuation is ignored when testing for palindromes, so "Doc, note:..." should return true.  Likewise,  "Never odd or even" should return true.

Comment: You could also go one step further here and add a reverse method to the String prototype (in js) so you could do: "test".reverse(). This keeps the code nicely encapsulated and re-usable. With it being on the prototype, every instance gets the same function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Boolean expression returns

This applies to both your Javascript and Python implementations:

```javascript
if (reversed_string_1 === original_string && reversed_string_2 === original_string && reversed_string_3 === original_string && reversed_string_4 === original_string) {
    return true;
    // If the original string is not a palindrome
} else {
    return false;
}
```

```python
if reverse_string_slice(original_string) == original_string and reverse_string(original_string) == original_string:
    return True
return False
```

Your expression is already a boolean; you don't need an `if`. In other words,

```
return reverse_string_slice(original_string) == original_string and reverse_string(original_string) == original_string
```

### Boolean comparison

```
if check_palindrome(word) == True:
```

should simply be

```
if check_palindrome(word):
```

Also, the convention is that boolean-valued functions are named like `is_palindrome`.

### `words_array`

First of all: This isn't an array, because Python doesn't have those. It's a list. Second, just call it `words` - usually it's not useful to include the type of a variable in its name. Finally: you shouldn't even be using a list, because you won't be mutating (modifying) it; use a `tuple` (in parens, not brackets).

Comment: Technically, Python does have [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). However, they are rarely used. The term "array" is also used in the context of `numpy`.

Comment: That's fair. It's more accurate to say that Python has arrays, but they aren't first-class.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, your `check_palindrome` function can be made more efficient and *pythonic*:

```
def check_palindrome(original_string):
    """Returns true if an input string is a palindrome"""
    original_string = original_string.lower()
    return all(r == o for r, o in zip(reversed(original_string), original_string[:len(original_string)//2]))
```

This only iterates over half of the characters as opposed to your version. You could also use islice from itertools, for example:

```
def check_palindrome(original_string):
    """Returns true if an input string is a palindrome"""
    original_string = original_string.lower()
    original = islice(original_string, len(original_string) // 2)
    return all(r == o for r, o in zip(reversed(original_string), original))
```

Also note that docstrings should be double quoted.

Comment: `original_string[::len(original_string)//2]` should be `original_string[:len(original_string)//2]`.